# XML parsing Issue in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the following (just a chunk here) of an XML file (subtitles)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <document id="6736625">
      <s id="1">
        <time id="T1S" value="00:02:54,941" />
        - Le requin t'a eue.
      </s>
      <s id="2">
        - Tu es sérieuse ?
      </s>
      <s id="3">
        Regarde ce que tu as fait.
        <time id="T1E" value="00:02:58.251" />
      </s>
      <s id="4">
        <time id="T2S" value="00:02:58,351" />
        Je vais t'en chercher un autre.
      </s>
      <s id="5">
        On peut faire quelque chose, je m'ennuie....
        <time id="T2E" value="00:03:01,249" />
      </s>
      ...
```

with following Python code

```
tree = ET.parse('data/6736625.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
myPhrasesArray = [""]

for q in root:
    try:
        a = q.text
        b = a
        myPhrasesArray.append(b)
    except :
        print(" arh ")

print(myPhrasesArray)
```

but it returns :

```
['', '', '- Tu es sérieuse ?', 'Regarde ce que tu as fait.', 
 '', "On peut faire quelque chose, je m'ennuie....", '', '', 
 "J'ai promis à Stuart de l'appeler.", '', '- A tes ordres.', 
 .....
```

I can t seem to find a way to get the text value for "/s" if there is an ID time/ value line before the actual text.

Any help ???

Comment: `q in root` is every single tag, but the `time` tags have empty text. What do you want to happen for the time tags?

Comment: I want to get  all  the text lines and just throw away timers. And store those text sentences in an array

Answer (score 0):

Try it using lxml:

```
import lxml.html
subt = [your html above]
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(subt)
dialog = doc.xpath('//*/text()')
myPhrasesArray = []
for d in dialog:
    if len(d.strip())>0:
        myPhrasesArray.append(d.strip())
myPhrasesArray
```

Output:

```
["- Le requin t'a eue.",
 '- Tu es sérieuse ?',
 'Regarde ce que tu as fait.',
 "Je vais t'en chercher un autre.",
 "On peut faire quelque chose, je m'ennuie...."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing `for q in root`, you want to only iterate over `s` tags.

You can use `ElementTree.iter()` or `ElementTree.findall()`. The former looks in everything no matter how deep. The latter only looks at direct children. For the example you've given `findall()` would make more sense.

```
myPhrasesArray = [] # just start with it empty
for s in root.findall('s'):
    myPhrasesArray.append(s.text)
```

Given this is pretty simple, you could even do it in one line:

```
myPhrasesArray = [s.text for s in root.findall('s')]
```

Comment: sorted it out using .itertext since none of findall or iter worked (tried that at the very begining)  I ve put a sample of the code in answer if someone feels interested

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way

```
parsedXml = ET.parse("data/tst/1914/"+ str(filename))
            root = parsedXml.getroot()

            for child in root:
                try:
                    if child.tag == "s":
                        a = ''.join(child.itertext()).strip().lower()
                        if a.startswith("-"):
                            a = a.lstrip("-")
                            mySentences.append(a)
```